# Prevent powershell prompt from closing until job finishes

Tags: powershell

I have a job which runs for ~20 min but the powershell prompt closes the window in 15 min and throws an error email (as per my script). However the job keep running in the background and completes successfully.

How do I prevent powershell prompt from closing until the job finishes.

The below code does not seem to be working.

```
 Start-Job -Name Job1 -ScriptBlock {
      --- Perform command
 }
 Wait-Job -Name Job1
```

If I try to use the sleep command, I still receive the error email after 15 min even thought the prompt does not close.

Comment: what is the error message you get?

Comment: What is the script block? How is the script being delivered - is it running inside an SCCM Task Sequence with a 15minute timeout? Please provide more details.

Comment: I am running a Hyperion utility (epmautomate) to update the metadata in the application.

     Start-Job -Name Job1 -ScriptBlock { $EPMAutomateBatch loaddimdata $AppName dataFileName=$FileName
      }
      Wait-Job -Name Job1

     Error message is EPMAT-1:Read timed out